# No feedback on application, now applying for a new position in that company

Tags: interviewing, job-search, feedback

I applied for a job back at a large software company back in December and got an email from HR saying that I would get a reply within 4 weeks.

I never received any reply and I am fairly certain now that the job went to someone else. I now see that there is a **new opening** in the same company (yet *different* department) that is interesting to me and I would like to apply for it.

However, I am worried why my original application in December didn't get any feedback. Should I

1. Contact HR and politely ask what happened
2. Contact the group leader directly and ask him
3. Leave it and focus on the new opening, maybe contact the group leader for the new department and let her know of my concerns and ask if I can send the application to her directly?

At the end of the day, I don't want to give the wrong impression, yet I want to make sure that my application actually gets read.

Comment: It is more common than not to not receive feedback if you were not selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should contact HR first, and simply explain the situation, as you just did here.

There is a new job opening, which is interesting for you with the company, you wish to apply, and you would like to know their guidelines for such an application, especially since you have a pending application. If their process is not crystal-clear, ask them the permission to directly talk with the group leader - maybe even to arrange the interview.

You will get, as a side bonus effect, some information on your current status too.